Showing/hiding elements without disruption to other view elements
I have been using opacity as a way to show or hide view elements without disrupting the layout of views. In this example I want Label to always remain horizontally centered regardless of info1 or info2 images being shown or not.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var info1: Bool = false
    @State var info2: Bool = false
    @State var label: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter label", text: $label)
                .frame(width: 200)
            Toggle("Info 1", isOn: $info1)
                .frame(width: 100)
            Toggle("Info 2", isOn: $info2)
                .frame(width: 100)
                    
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
                    .opacity(info1 ? 1 : 0)
                Text(label)
                Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
                    .opacity(info2 ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm sure there is a better way, but so far haven't found one that is adaptable to work in more complex views.  Any suggestions?

When an image (or view) of unknown size is sometimes visible, but sometimes not, setting opacity is fine for preserving the layout. But you could also consider techniques in which the views are shown conditionally (that is, using an if statement). This means reserving the same amount of space when the view is not showing.
The choice of technique might depend on how you want to animate the change. A change of opacity can of course be animated smoothly. But a view that is being shown conditionally can be animated in other ways, using transitions.
Here are some ways of showing the views conditionally:

If in fact you know the size of the view being hidden then you can just use padding to reserve the necessary space for it. For your example, if the images would have a max width of 20, you could add horizontal padding to the Text (allowing for spacing too) and then show the images as overlays. The position of an overlay can be controlled by supplying an .alignment parameter. An HStack is no longer needed:

Text(label)
    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        if info1 {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
                .frame(maxWidth: 20, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
        if info2 {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
                .frame(maxWidth: 20, alignment: .trailing)
        }
    }


For a view with an unknown size, you can also use .hidden() for a version that is never visible, but is present as a placeholder to influence the layout. Applying this to your example, you could include hidden versions of the images on both sides of the label and then show the visible versions as overlays, as before:

HStack {
    Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill").hidden()
    Text(label)
    Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill").hidden()
}
.overlay(alignment: .leading) {
    if info1 {
        Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
    }
}
.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
    if info2 {
        Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
    }
}


If the HStack should have either maximum width or a fixed width, but the label should always be centered, you could put a Spacer between the images and show the label as an overlay:

HStack {
    if info1 {
        Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
    }
    Spacer()
    if info2 {
        Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
    }
}
.overlay {
    Text(label)
}


If the label might be taller than the images then you can make it a ZStack instead:

ZStack {
    HStack {
        if info1 {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
        }
        Spacer()
        if info2 {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
        }
    }
    Text(label)
}


Since reading your comment and experimenting more, I also tried, with good results, applying .overlay() with an .offset(x:) to display Image() on either side of Text() label.  This does not appear to affect layout.

@Rhythmus Correct, an overlay does not affect the layout. However, if you use .offset to move the overlay outside the bounds of the view below it, there is a risk that the overlay will overlap with other screen content or even go off the screen. So if the overlay is shown at the side of the underlying view, I would normally try to reserve space for it using the techniques shown. Actually I updated the first example (using padding) to use overlays too, I think it's a better way.
